# Is it possible to send different normals to a triangle strip vertex based on which face it is part of

Tags: opengl

I am drawing a simple triangle strip cube with these vertices:

```
((0.5, 0.5, 0.5),
 (-0.5, 0.5, 0.5),
 (0.5, -0.5, 0.5),
 (-0.5, -0.5, 0.5),
 (-0.5, -0.5, -0.5),
 (-0.5, 0.5, 0.5),
 (-0.5, 0.5, -0.5),
 (0.5, 0.5, 0.5),
 (0.5, 0.5, -0.5),
 (0.5, -0.5, 0.5),
 (0.5, -0.5, -0.5),
 (-0.5, -0.5, -0.5),
 (0.5, 0.5, -0.5),
 (-0.5, 0.5, -0.5))
```

What I realized is that you pass one normal for each vertex. The problem with this is that each vertex is being used for three faces. Thus, there is one normal passed for three face corners. This results in some truly odd visuals:
[image: example 1]

(Note that this was produced with diffuse lighting, and no attenuation)

So, my question, Can you pass different normals to a vertex, based on which face it is being used for? Currently, I have found that you can pass one normal for all of one vertex's face calculations, but it results in an odd visual effect.

Comment: No, it is not. You have to create multiple attribute tuples.

Comment: ok. Is there still a way to do this with one triangle strip, or would I have to use triangles?

Comment: You have to use tringles. Just the 2 tringles which form a side of the cube have the same normal.